# Wordpress site loses style partially when logged out

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

The sticky header and `h2` tags lose their styling when viewed as a guest i.e. when I am not logged in.

Has anyone ever seen this issue? I am using theme Avada 5.2.0.

The site appears like this when I am logged in:

[image]

When logged out or this is how a normal visitor sees the website

[image]

P.S The italics have been added on that point

Comment: sent website url?

Comment: if you are using a plugin for caching, clear the cache by going to that plugin settings. If you are not using a cache plugin, then you don't need to do it.